# Limit queryset in Django Tastypie

Tags: django, api, rest, tastypie

I am building an application with django and tastypie and try to load objects via ajax.
For example I display 3 objects then once the user reach the last I load 3 more etc.

So I am trying to modify the queryset in the tastypie api but can't find how to do this.
In the ajax call I send a parameter `start` that defines the beginning of the limit. But I don't know where I can access this parameters and modify the queryset.

```
class EntryResource(ModelResource):

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        # I can get the parameter here but it's not useful
        start = bundle.request['start']
        return bundle

    def get_object_list(self, request):
        # I can modify the objects returned here but how can I access bundle.request ?
        return super(EntryResource, self).get_object_list(request).filter(active=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Entry.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'entry'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. This was actually pretty easy but i'll write the answer in case it's useful for somebody else.

The solution is to use the paginator (I wasn't googling the right terms so I didn't find it at first).
I the ajax call I send the `offset` and `limit` parameters.

More: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/paginator.html

Comment: Default pagination in tastypie works without define paginator_class in the meta class of the resource. If you want to implement your own paginator then you have to define it to the Meta class.

Comment: Didn't see that. Thanks, I removed it from my answer as it's useless